# Python Equivalent for Deno's ensureDir

Tags: python, file-handling

What's the Python equivalent to Deno's [`ensureDir`](https://deno.land/std@0.144.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts?s=ensureDir)?

Usage example:

```
import { ensureDir, ensureDirSync } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts";
ensureDir("./logs").then(
  () => console.log("Success Created"),
).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`pathlib.Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir). Example:

```py
import pathlib

pathlib.Path.home().joinpath(".local", "extra", "path").mkdir(
    parents=True, exist_ok=True
)
```